# How to repeat a procedure for each value of an integer

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, integer, conditional-statements

In my application I have an integer, say in this example its name is `count` and its value is `5`.

For each value in this integer: 1,2,3,4,5, I want to trigger some sort of `foreach`/ `while` statement which will recur for each of the values.

In my current situation it's not possible to save each value of the integer in a `List<int>` so I can't use `foreach`.

I've looked at the `for` statement but don't understant quite how to use it, or if it is suitable for my needs in the current situation.

So does anyone know of some conditional statement I can use, or some kind of workaround? An example would be great!

Thanks.

Comment: What about [for](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ch45axte.aspx) do you not understand? It even has the exact same example (1 to 5). o_O

Comment: This is too basic to be a question. Its almost as basic as `how do I learn programming`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [for loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx):

```
for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
{
    //do something with i
}
```

Breaking this down.

A `for` loop is useful for when you want to run a piece of code X amount of times or when you need to iterate over a collection and access the elements via the index, usually with the help of a local variable named `i`.

- `i` is first initialized to a default value you provide; 1 in this case
- Next, the expression `i <= count` is evaluated. This will be false initially due to 1 (`i`) being less than 5 (`count`)
- The code inside of the block is then executed
- The value of `i` is incremented via `i++` - if you're having trouble understanding what `i++` does, please see the comments
- The expression `i <= count` is evaluated again. This happens until the expression returns false at which point execution leaves the loop.

Comment: Could you explain what `i++` does please?

Comment: [++ Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/36x43w8w.aspx) - you might want to consider making yourself a bit more familiar with the absolute basics of the language you're using.

Comment: `i++` will increment `i` by 1. It's similar to the line `i = i + 1`

Comment: @DGibbs - should've used `i += 1` and waited for the next question. ^_^ (Sorry OP, it's not meant personally. I just find it odd, that you know about `List<int>` and `foreach` which is usually a bit more advanced than `for` or `++`)

Answer (score 2):

the difference between the foreach and the for loop is only, that you must specify the number of elements upon initialization.

So the code sample

```
for(int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
{
    //do
}
```

simply says: take an integer i, give it a value to start with and while this integer is less than or equal count, do what's in the braces and increment it.

so

```
for(int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
{
    printf("\nlook at my%i", i);
}
```

would simply print

```
look at my 1
look at my 2
look at my 3
look at my 4
look at my 5
```

to console. The \n ist just a "newline"

Answer (score 1):

use `for` loop but if you are persistent with `foreach` use `Enumerable.Range()`

```
foreach (int num in Enumerable.Range(1, 5))
{
    Console.WriteLine(num);
}
```